# Make sound or play audio in the background agent in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is it possible to play a piece of audio (very short) in the background agent in Windows Phone? Not background music. What I want to achieve is to tell user what the time is every half an hour.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's a tutorial with a sample project:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: This is probably not what I needed. Maybe my question needs to be clarified. Please see my edited question

Comment: @imgen so if I have this right, you already have a background agent with a scheduled task (see http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_create_simple_Background_Agent_in_Windows_Phone), and you want a sound to play every 30 mins? Perhaps you could create a new notification to go off and play a custom sound?